# Running a batch file inside WinForms?

Tags: c#

I tried to look around for this but never found a real solution.

I want to embed a `ConsoleApplication` inside a WinForms GUI. Like, run the application and embed it into a tab in a `TabControl`.

Is it possible? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found an awesome control: [ConsoleControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConsoleControl/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to redirect the standard input and output of the application you are trying to run. This is done using an inter-process communication mechanism called anonymous pipes.

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) describes how to use them to redirect standard input and output of a child process.